# js Remove a part from a parameter which doesnt fit a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
const regex = /[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}/gm;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(tweet.text)) !== null) {
let newClass = tweet.text.replace(/[^1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[^1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[^1-9a-zA-Z]{3}/g, '');
console.log(`Found match: ${newClass}`);
};
```

when `tweet.text = "123.qwe.456 test"` I still get the same output but I want to remove anything which doesnt fit the pattern

`/[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}/`

any ideas?

Comment: We can see the regex you wrote, but what is "the pattern" that you are _trying_ to exclude? That is, you are getting `"123.qwe.456 test"`, which part of that do you want to exclude? What is the _desired_ output?

Comment: The string, so the input is variable. Meaning that "test" needs to b replaced with nothing. I want to replace everything but the matching string with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const regex = /[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}/gm;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(tweet.text)) !== null) {
console.log(`Found match: ${m[0]}`);
```

figured the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture groups to extract exactly what gets matched in your string and then replace your original variable with this value. Something like

```
const regex = /([1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}-[1-9a-zA-Z]{3})/
let match = tweet.text.match(regex)
tweet.text = match[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace, you can get the match instead

```
\b[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}([-.])[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}\1[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}` Match 3 times any of the listed (Note that 1-9 does not match a 0)
- `([-.])` Capture in **group 1** either an `-` or `.`
- `[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}` Match 3 times any of the listed
- `\1` Back reference to group 1, match the same as captured in group 1
- `[1-9a-zA-Z]{3}` Match 3 times any of the listed
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MjARcC/1)